# Learning Powershell and accessing nest JSON objects using ForEach

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

I am currently running into road blocks trying to wrap my head around the way to access items nested within other objects. I would like to access the nested items and list their details as a table. I want to display the details of "One", "Two", "Three" as a table.

Here is the JSON

```
{
 "ToCover":{
        "ToDo":{
            "One":{
                "ID":1,
                "Task": "Bezlio & Handheld testing",
                "Comment":"",
                "InProgress": "In Progress"
            },
            "Two":{
                "ID":2,
                "Task": "Crystal Default reports to SSRS default",
                "Comment":"Moved all",
                "InProgress": "Complete"
            },
            "Three":{
                "ID":3,
                "Task": "new system Install",
                "Comment": "Delayed",
                "InProgress": "In Progress"
        }
     }     
  }   
}
```

Here is the powershell script

```
$test = 
foreach ($task in $json.ToCover.ToDo){
    foreach($item in $task){
        foreach($detail in $item){
            $detail
        }
    } 
}

$test
```

Here is an example of what I was hoping to achieve:

```
$table = foreach ($task in $json.ToCover.ToDo){
    $json.ToCover.ToDo.One
    $json.ToCover.ToDo.Two
    $json.ToCover.ToDo.Three
}
```

Comment: seems like you're looking for `$json.ToCover.ToDo.PSObject.Properties.Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to access the Value of each property in `.ToDo` without knowing the property Names, to access and reflect on the members of an object (properties, methods and other information about the object) you can use the [`PSObject` intrinsic member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.3#object-views):

```
$json.ToCover.ToDo.PSObject.Properties.Value
```

Would output the `Value` of each property via [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2).